# Should I keep my change password section within the change profile section or settings?

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, smartphone, password-change

I've seen some mobile apps keep the change password section separately from the edit profile screen (for instance Instagram) but some just keep it inside the edit profile screen itself.

I personally am accustomed to looking for the settings icon whenever I want to change my password but since my app is not really that big and does not really have much to put in settings, I feel like I should just get rid of settings and put the change password in edit profile.

My app currently has this sort of structure:

[image]

My profile will have edit profile option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand where all the current items under Settings would live if you remove the parent element but in any case, context wise I think password management belongs to an account or profile section. Have you considered renaming **My Profile** to **My Account**?

EDIT: I'm asking because profile relates to content about the user but account has a more global reach that could potentially allocate both personal information and subscription management.

Answer (score 0):

Password change should be under  Settings. You can merge settings and privacy and keep those content together. It will be easier for the user to look for password change.