# Where would you look for your password settings?

Tags: password, settings, app, profile

Organizing app info. Where would you expect to find your password settings - under settings or under profile?

Comment: Related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/132264/should-i-keep-my-change-password-section-within-the-change-profile-section-or-se

Answer (score 1):

**Profile**

Along with settings such as name and email.

If there is no profile, I would go to settings. Settings is usually more about settings of the application (language, dark mode).

Answer (score 0):

I also agree with the **Profile** option, however, regardless if you put it in Profile or Settings, make sure it is in a **Security** or **Privacy & Security** page.